# Laravel Voyager Change Background of RichTextBox

Tags: laravel, background, tinymce, voyager

I have a voyager project, in a model, in a RichTextBox field, the text written is white, also the default background of the TinyMCE is white, that leads to not being able to see the text, the only way i can edit it is through the "Source Code".

Is it possible to change the background of the RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncomment following lines in the voyager config file:  **/config/voyager.php**

```php
 'additional_css' => [
     //'css/custom.css',
     'css/custom.css',
 ],

 'additional_js' => [
     //'js/custom.js',
     'js/custom.js',
 ],
```

2. Create css and js files:

   - /public/css/custom.css
   - /public/js/custom.js
3. Add the following script to the js file: **/public/js/custom.js**

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var iframe = document.getElementById('richtextbody_ifr');
      var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
      var full = location.pathname;
      cssLink.href = "/css/custom.css"; 
      cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
      cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
      iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(cssLink);
    });
```

4. Add your CSS code to /public/css/custom.css

**For example:**

```css
#tinymce{
  background-color: black;
}
```

> *The above solution works for 'RichTextBox/TinyMCE',
>   For styling Voyager UI the JS script is not needed.*